# Using multiple key values for dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Trying to make program output a grade for a percentage entered:

```
percentage=90
grades={percentage>=80:'A',
        percentage>=60:'B',
        percentage>=40:'C',
        percentage<39:'Fail'}
print(grades[percentage])
```

Initially want the program to print 'A'

---

Instead I get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 10, in <module>
print(grades[percentage])
KeyError: 90
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is desired output?

Comment: the string value 'A' as percentage is above 80

Comment: Maybe you're confusing the purpose of a dictionary with that of a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're treating a `dict` like a function which returns values by evaluating keys as logical statements.  A `dict` is a store of fixed key-value pairs; it doesn't work the way you're expecting it to.

You can either write a function to evaluate a given grade, or, you can create a `dict` that contains every possible score-grade pair, and look up grades by score.

It seems like the second approach is more what you're going for, but the problem is that calling `grades[percentage]` requires there be an exact `percentage` stored in the `grades` dict.  I'd recommend building a function instead.

This looks like it might be part of some kind of homework assignment, so I'll leave a starting point that you can build off of.  Something like this:

```
def compute_grade(p):
    if grade >= 80:
        return 'A'
    elif grade >= 60:
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function

```
def grade(percentage):
    if percentage >= 80:
        return 'A'
    elif percentage >= 60:
        return 'B'
    elif percentage >= 40:
        return 'C'
    else:
        return 'Fail'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a dictionary where each key is a boolean value based on the results of the each comparison.

```
percentage=90
grades={percentage>=80:'A',
    percentage>=60:'B',
    percentage>=40:'C',
    percentage<39:'Fail'}
```

Thus, dictionary is actually:

```
{False: 'Fail', True: 'C'}
```

Instead, create a structure that utilizes `range`:

```
class Data:
   def __init__(self):
      self.grades = {tuple(range(80, 101)):'A', tuple(range(60, 80)):'B', tuple(range(40, 60)):'C'}
   def __getitem__(self, val):
      return "Fail" if not [b for a, b in self.grades.items() if val in a] else [b for a, b in self.grades.items() if val in a][0]
d = Data()
print(d[90])
```

Output:

```
'A'
```

Comment: Why not use a simple function: `def grades(percentage):
  if percentage >= 80: return 'A'
  if percentage >= 60: return 'B'
  if percentage >= 40: return 'C'
  return 'Fail'
`

Comment: @tonypdmtr good point, however, I wanted to retain the OP's dictionary style approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use dictionary.. this is one dirty way to use it.

```
percentage=70
grades={80:'A',
        60:'B',
        40:'C',
        39:'Fail'}

grade_vals = grades.keys()
obtained_grade = 'NONE'
# Sorting is super necessary
grade_vals.sort(reverse = True)
for grade in grade_vals:
    if percentage > grade:
        obtained_grade = grades[grade]
        break

print(obtained_grade)
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the `.keys()` are sorted? if not the break; might break wrongly ...

Comment: Interesting have a point there, I totally forgot that the keys won't be sorted. Have edited the code for that.Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

This relates to the order in which Python evaluates expressions.

You've used boolean expressions as keys in the `grades` dictionary. When the `grades` dictionary is being evaluated, first the booleans will be evaluated, then the dictionary will be instantiated.

So we start with

```
grades={percentage>=80:'A',
        percentage>=60:'B',
        percentage>=40:'C',
        percentage<39:'Fail'}
```

Since `percentage` has been set to `90`, the first three conditions are `True` and the last one is `False`, so the dictionary becomes:

```
grades={True:'A',
        True:'B',
        True:'C',
        False:'Fail'}
```

I expect if you tried doing `print(grades[False])` you would get `'Fail'`.

Instead, I suggest you key the dictionary on the lower grade boundary:

```
grades={80: 'A',
        60: 'B',
        40: 'C',
        0: 'Fail'}
```

Then iterate over the dictionary and select the grade that is nearest to `precentage`, but not greater than it:

```
grade_boundary = min([x for x in grades.keys() if percentage > x])
grade = grades[grade_boundary]
```